# Pivot in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have data as below:

```
A
B
C
D
E
E
F
```

Expectation is to convert row to column:

```
A B C D E E F
```

I have tried defining the previous values comparing with current value

```
Column1 = Input Column
v1 = Column1
v2 = IFF(Column1 = v1, v2, Column1)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your variable port like:

```
v1 = v1 + Column1
```

And define the output port as:

```
outPivot = v1
```

Keep in mind this will keep the amount of rows pretty much the same. So as you need just the last one use `Aggregator`. By default, if you won't define groups, it will aggregate all into one row. And by default it will use `LAST` function to perform the aggregation, which is exactly what you need.